# Source an R file multiple times in test to reset mockery stubs?

Tags: r

I'm running a test, like the following where I am running source() within each test. My thought is that each time I run source() that R is resetting the stubbed out function 'firstFunction', that I'm quickly getting back to the default state. Is this what is happening when a re-run source() on the same file? Are there any gotchas from re-running source() multiple times?

### File: fakeTest.R

```
library(testthat)
library(mockery)
describe("test group",{
  it("first test", {
    source("src/R/my_code.R")
    m <- mock(TRUE)
    stub(firstFunction,'calledFunction',m)
    # run test here
    expect_called(m,1)
  })
  it("second test", {
    source("src/R/my_code.R")
    m <- mock(FALSE)
    stub(firstFunction,'calledFunction',m)
    # run test here
    expect_called(m,1)
  })
})
```